# XCode how to stop a build if there are strings referencing localhost or other

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, clang, static-analysis

We are looking for ways to stop a build if it is being built for release and contains strings that reference "localhost" or containing "10.0" or other rules. does xCode have a way of enforcing these rules?

Comment: You can add a shell script build phase running `strings -a` on the executable, `grep` what you (don't) want, and `error` when required.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom shell script build phase to your project.. you can run whatever shell script you want in there. You can also inspect the plethora of build environment variables, including one which should tell you if you are building for release or debug.

Comment: More specifically, use find to get to every .m file, then search in each for the strings of interest, returning an error value if any found.